# SignalR: Connection.Start().Wait() hangs the browser indefinitely

Tags: signalr.client

I am using ver 0.5.3 of SignalR assembly in my silverlight application. I use connection.Start().wait() to start the connection:
Some of my observations are, which are really strange:

1. I run the application (In-Browser) mode via Visual Studio and I am able to establish the connection with the SignalR hub
2. If I deploy the app in IIS and then try accessing the application using the IP address of the machine, the call to connection.start().wait() never returns. I checked the Fiddler and figured out that the call never goes to the SignalR hub
3. If I use the application in OOB mode (Out of Browser mode), application works without any issue.

My requirement is that it should work in in-Browser mode.
Can somebody throw some light, what could be the issue?

Thanks,
Alpee

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are running into Silverlight's [cross-domain request restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) when run in-browser. You can either host the silverlight application on the same domain that is running SignalR, or you could add a clientaccesspolicy.xml or crossdomain.xml file to the root of the domain running SignalR as suggested in the above link.